# php glob with wildcard issue as it lists all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, glob

i have these file names which i want to delete

```
 Desert-100x100.jpg
     Desert-1024x768.jpg
 Desert-150x150.jpg 
  Desert-300x225.jpg
```

but dont want to delete file names

```
  Desert-e1536645590208-300x217.jpg
   Desert-e1536645590208-768x555.jpg
```

i have used these globs code and i think it is working a expected

```
   foreach(glob("Desert-*[100-9999]x[100-9999]*.{jpg,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE) as $file){ 

  unlink ($file);


   }
```

but my problem is we want to exclude certain file type or more specifically files that contain e1536645590208which is dynamic and we dnt have control so we can use stripos and filter out those without e1536645590208 but i think there must be some glob parameters which will allow us to filter result without using stripos or some other means.

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: @Sam php.......................

Comment: ok. since their doesn't seem to be some sort of bash "extglob" equivalent in php, this might actually get a little tricky with just globbing. do i understand right that the files you want to exclude always contain at least one "-" more than the ones you want to include? can you otherwise specify in more detail, what shape the "dynamic" pattern may take?

Comment: note that the patterns in your brackets are probably not doing quite what you expect. the part in the brackets matches ONE character from the specified range, which boils down to [0-9].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glob doesn't understand regex, `*` means 0 or more any character, it is not a quantifier.

Use this

```
glob("Desert-{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}*x*.{jpg,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

Or

```
glob("Desert-[1-9]*x*.{jpg,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE);
```

It will select files that have a digit just afer `Desert-` so it will skip all files that have `e.....`